# Customise the color of a token which does not have a "semantic type" in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, customization

I can override the color of certain types of token in my settings.json:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
      "type": {
        "foreground": "#777",
      }
}
```

That works by using the "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" command:

[image]

But not all tokens have a "semantic token type", like the word "Types" here:

[image]

Is there a way to target this token type in `settings.json` to change its color?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in this specific case, this works:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "types": "#777"
  },
```

But how to infer `types` from the values in that popup, I don't know.